# How to alter text orientation to vertical in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

Using MS Excel I can go to Format of the cell and choose the text orientation from horizontal to vertical fairly easily.

How do I alter text orientation to vertical in Google Sheets?

Comment: There's a "format -> text rotation" option for this in Sheets now.  :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Select your cell
2. Replace its content with the following formula:

   ```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE((MID( "Text to become vertical"; ROW(INDIRECT("YY1:YY"&LEN( "Text to become vertical" ))); 1)&CHAR(10))))
   ```
3. Repeat for each cell

Observation: make sure the text you want in your cell is the same in both instances of the formula.

From here: http://www.quikstarts.com/Internet/Google-Docs/how-to-make-vertical-column-headers-in-google-docs/

Comment: Almost there but not quiet since I have to make it for each cell. I think I can live with this. :) Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Here is a regex based solution:

```
= regexreplace( "Text", "(.)", "$1"&char(10) )
```

Translation: Look in the input "Text", which could be a cell reference too, and find each instance of the regular expression `.`, i.e., each single character. Store the matched character in a sub-expression so we can use it later by putting the regex within parentheses. Then replace each match with the string concatenation of itself via sub-expression reference `"$1"` along with the newline character `char(10)`.

Comment: That's a good one !!

Comment: Why don't you throw in an `ARRAYFORMULA` version?

Comment: Nice and short regex formula, I like it :)

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Why would you need an ARRAYFORMULA version?

Answer (score 7):

You have do create it as a drawing. See [here](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179740) for more details on how to create word art.

Answer (score 6):

As of 22 February 2017, support for rotated text will be introduced:

[image]

### Note

Gradual rollout (potentially longer than 3 days for feature visibility)

### Reference

Blog post reference: **[Support for rotated text in Google Sheets](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/02/support-for-rotated-text-accounting.html)**

Answer (score 3):

If a cell is narrow, then here is a quick and dirty approach. 
Type the word into the spreadsheet cell with a space between each later:

> V e r t i c a l   T e x t

Then make the width of the column narrow so that text wrapping will stack the letters vertically.

```
V
e
r
t
i
c
a
l

T
e
x
t
```

This will only work if the cell has a width of one letter. If the cell is wider, then the formula approach is best.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine a couple of the approaches suggested in some other answers by creating a custom function in [Tools > Script Editor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

```
function VERTICAL_TEXT(text) {
  var vert_text = text.replace(/(.)/g,"$1\n");
  return vert_text;
}
```

And then using it in the cell:

```
=VERTICAL_TEXT("cell contents")
```

Comment: It does through in an extra "\n".

Answer (score 2):

Place the cursor between two characters, hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to create a line break between the chars.

Answer (score 2):

Until we have real vertical test, it's the simplest to leave the text orientation horizontal and spread each heading over several cells using the cell merge function, in a stairlike fashion:

[image: Stairlike grid fashion]

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Insert-Image" and create a text box, rotate it and click save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Insert > Draw, create a text box and rotate it. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way (now) seems to be to select range and Format > Text rotation > Stack vertically.